# Ubuntu 14.04 - Low Resolution Set To 1024x768

Tags: 14.04, screen

My monitory is 1920x1080 and I can't seem to change the resolution any higher than 1024x768.

Comment: What type of graphics card do you have?

Comment: I have a GTX 950. I am also having trouble downloading drivers for it.

Comment: Do `wget -O nvidia.run http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/352.63/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-352.63.run` and then do `sudo apt-get install build-essential -y` after that do `sudo sh ./nvidia.run` after that just restart your computer and it should work fine.